# I use color with left color, right color and fill in tikz, but why are these two cases different？

Tags: tikz-pgf

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[left color=BlueGreen,right color=BlueGreen] (0,0) rectangle (2,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[fill=BlueGreen] (0,0) rectangle (2,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

The result is
[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The one is a shading, the other a fill and in the default setting they use different color models (rgb + cmyk). You can force the same color model:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\section{rgb}
\selectcolormodel{rgb}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[left color=BlueGreen,right color=BlueGreen] (0,0) rectangle (2,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[fill=BlueGreen] (0,0) rectangle (2,1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\section{cmyk}
\selectcolormodel{cmyk}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[left color=BlueGreen,right color=BlueGreen] (0,0) rectangle (2,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[fill=BlueGreen] (0,0) rectangle (2,1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]